# Having trouble making more than 1 clickable object

Tags: python, pygame, mouse, selection

I am a student trying to figure out how to make multiple clickable objects in pygame.

I was able to make 1 working clickable object (dx,dy) work, but when I tried to make another clickable object (qx,qy), every time I run my code and click on where the object should be, nothing happens.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, so it would be great if someone could give me some advice.

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
display = pygame.display.set_mode([1000,600])
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
dx,dy=105,470
qx,qy=750,465

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if mouse[0]in range (dx,dy) and mouse[1] in range (dx,dy+50):
                print("Hello love.")
            elif mouse[0] in range (qx,qy+50) and mouse[1] in range (qx,qy+50):
                print("No")


    pygame.font.init()
    fontcolor = pygame.Color("white")
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS",35,True,False)
    label1 = myfont.render("Draw Card",1,(200,200,200))
    d = display.blit(label1, (dx,dy))
    label2 = myfont.render("Quite",1,(200,200,200))
    q = display.blit(label2, (qx,qy))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: I don't really understand why even your first clickable object works, since you seem to be mixing up X and Y components in your checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ranges make no sense. `range(qx,qy+50)` and `range(qx,qy+50)` are empty because the first argument is greater than the second. The dx, dy range checks also don't work correctly.

You have to check if `mouse[0]` is between `dx` and `dx+50` and if `mouse[1]` is between `dy` and `dy+50` and the same for `qx, qy`.

```
if mouse[0] in range(dx, dx+50) and mouse[1] in range(dy, dy+50):
    print("Hello love.")
elif mouse[0] in range(qx, qx+50) and mouse[1] in range(qy, qy+50):
    print("No")
```

Note that the size of the clickable area will only be 50*50 px and you should better figure out how big the text surfaces are instead of just adding `50` to dx, etc..

It would be even better to use `pygame.Rect`s. You can create the rects with the [`get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) method of the text surfaces and then use the [`collidepoint`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) method for the collision detection and just blit the surfaces at the corresponding rects.

Here's a minimal, complete example:

```
import sys
import pygame


pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode([1000,600])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS",35,True,False)
fontcolor = pygame.Color("white")
label1 = myfont.render("Draw Card",1,(200,200,200))
label2 = myfont.render("Quite",1,(200,200,200))
label1_rect = label1.get_rect(topleft=(105, 470))
label2_rect = label2.get_rect(topleft=(750, 465))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            if label1_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):  # event.pos is the mouse position.
                print("Hello love.")
            elif label2_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                print("No")

    display.fill((30, 30, 30))
    d = display.blit(label1, label1_rect)
    q = display.blit(label2, label2_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```